# Booting Live system of Ubuntu 18.04.2 failes with many PCIe Bus Errors

Tags: 18.04, nvidia-geforce, pcie

I have a Ubuntu 18.04.2 image on a USB Stick.

On my old PC (~8 years) I can boot Ubuntu from the stick.

On my new PC booting shows only a page full (~50) of the following errors:

> PCIe Bus Error severity=Corrected type=Transaction Layer
>   id=000b(Receiver ID) device [1022:14531] error
>   status/mask=00002000/0000000 Adversory NonFatal

Then the system is frozen.

I also tried to boot Mint Linux 19.1 and Suse Leap 15 as live systems. Always the same result.

My PC: 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1700 - 
Motherboard: MSI B350 Gaming Pro Carbon - 
RAM: 2 x 16GB 2666-16 Vengeance LPX - 
Graphics: Gainward 8GB D5X GTX 1080 Phoenix - 
HDD: WD 3TB WD30EZRZ Blue 5400 SA3 - 
SSD: Samsung 512GB 860 PROBasic

Can anybody tell me what causes this problem and how it can be solved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is your NVIDIA graphics card not supported by the default open-source driver. You nees to boot the installer with an additional boot parameter, `nomodeset`, install amd use it again until you also install NVIDIA drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I merged two options (`pcie_aspm=off` and `nomodeset`) into this one answer that helped me resolve this issue:

**To edit Grub2 during the boot process try the following:**
(from [stackoverflow answer slightly changed](https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/224340))

1. Immediately after the BIOS splash screen during boot, press and hold the SHIFT button. This will display you grub containing a list of kernels and recovery options

   [image]
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the first kernel displayed

   [image]
3. Find the line ending with `quiet splash`. Add your boot option before these key words - i.e. so the line looks like [...]`pcie_aspm=off nomodeset quiet splash`
4. Press CTRL + X to boot

Follow the steps in [stackoverflow answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/38782/88802) on how to fix the nomodeset boot option permanently so that you don't have to go through this manual procedure again.

**To permanently set this setting, follow these steps:**
(from [this link slightly changed](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/PCIe_Bus_Error_Status_00001100))

Open the Grub configuration file in an editor after OS is booted, e. g. in vi:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Adjust the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT variable as follows, save the file and close the editor:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet pcie_aspm=off nomodeset"
```

After the configuration change, update the Grub Bootloader with the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Finally, restart the OS.

Drawback of this settings is that you may lose Power Management capabilities. (`ASPM` - Active State Power Management)